# Configure Reporting Service to open Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014, reportmanager

I recenlty install an instance of SSRS 2014. I want to alloiw my partners open Report Manager from their browser. When I go to this such address:

```
http://<HostName>/Reports
```

I can see Report Manager but they can't see Report Manager. IIS has been installed to my computer and when I enter:

```
http://<HostName>
```

It goes to IIS. I change the Report Manager port to 9051 using Reporting Service Configuration Manager and test this address:

```
http://<HostName>:9051/Reports
```

It works for my but it don't for my partners.

Is there any specific setting that I ignore it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you grant proper permission to your partners usernames?
you can to this in report manager > permissions tab.

Comment: mamnoon. Can you attach a screen shot that show permissions in Report Manager? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have any report server available but you can search in google images. I find this link for example: https://www.mssqltips.com/tipimages2/3144_SiteSettingsStart.JPG